# Rear wheel losing alignment

Tags: wheels, alignment

I've got an issue where my rear wheel is coming out of alignment. I can get it aligned just fine when seating it on the floor. When I close the skewer, everything looks good. I can bounce the bike up and down on the floor, free-crank it off the floor, and everything is still fine.

Then if I grab the brakes and put my weight on a pedal, I can watch the wheel snap back out of alignment.

I tried replacing the skewer with one from another bike, same result.

I do hear a lot crackling coming from the hanger (I believe), when I push and pull on it, and even when I close the skewer. I don't hear the same noise if I push and pull on the frame just above it. I can't see the hanger move, nor can I visibly see that it's bent, but I wonder if that could be part of the issue.

--UPDATE--

I swapped out with my road bike wheel and found that I cannot reproduce the issue with that one. Must be something with the hub or cups or whatever. Hopefully the bike shop can spot it.

Comment: What does the underside of the skewer's head and nut look like?  If they're rounded off, it may not be getting enough "bite" when clamped down.  Changing skewer should have resolved this, unless both are worn.